# Ubuntu 22.04へのリモートデスクトップ接続ができない

Tags: linux, ubuntu, rdp

macmbook m1 からUbuntu 22.04へリモートデスクトップ接続ができすに困っております。

Ubuntu 22.04側は設定から共有の設定は完了しており、Gnomeのactiveも確認できております。

mac側からはMicrosoft Remote Desktopを使用して接続を試みています。アカウント・パスワード入力後にこちらのようなエラーが出てきます。

[image: macから接続時のエラースクショ]

**参考サイト**
https://www.charasite.net/ubuntu-rdp/

少しでもアドバイスいただけますと幸いです。
必要情報ありましたら追記致します。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: WinodwsからUbuntuへ正常にリモートデスクトップが繋がりますか？また、MacからWindowsへも正常にリモートデスクトップが繋がりますか？

Comment: raccy様、ご返信ありがとうございます。申し訳ございませんがWindowsPCは持っていないので検証できません。

Comment: RDPはWindows向けに作られたプロトコルなので、他OSでの実装は不安定だったり、不具合が出たりすることはよくあります。Windowsがあれば、片方側の問題か、相性なのかがわかるのですが、Windowsとの相互運用も考えていないのであれば、RDP以外の選択肢を考えた方が良いかもしれません。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

アドバイスありがとうございました。

ubuntu側のシステムlogを確認したところ、[UFW BLOCK]となっており
結果的に、ポート3389が開いていないことが原因でした。

```
sudo ufw allow from any to any port 3389 proto tcp
```

こちらでポートを開けて、接続できるようになりました。